# Is it possible to close a specific <div> element?

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have a page where I provide a preview of a word (docx) document using docx_reader. I am using some key words to determine where to stop the preview, i.e., how much of the full docx to present. I then display that preview in a "div" element. However, since docx is essentially markup as well, I sometimes stop the preview (stop reading from the docx file) such that it leaves me with one or more unmatched open div elements which I am of course not closing in the main html code.

Now the question: is there a way to close a specific div element?

e.g.:

```
<div id="embedding_div">
   {$docx_preview}
</div id="embedding_div">
```

Alternatively, if this is not possible, how else can I present the preview so it does not mess with the surrounding code? Something like an iframe perhaps? Or is there a way to close all unmatched open divs from $docx_preview (e.g., using substr_count to find the number of opening and closing divs in $docx_preview and then add the missing number of closing divs) before I close embedding_div.

e.g.:

```
$nopen_divs=substr_count ($docx_preview, '<div>');
$nclose_divs=substr_count ($docx_preview, '</div>');
$nmissing_closedivs = $nopen_divs - $nclose_divs;
echo '<div id="embedding_div">';
echo $docx_preview;
for ($i=0;$i<$nmissing_closedivs;$i++){
   echo '</div>';
}
echo '</div>'; // this closes the embedding_div
```

Thanks in advance.

BTW, sometimes it also cuts in the middle of an element such as as "span". How can I prevent this? So the end of $docx_preview would be somehting like:

```
<span style="color: red
```

without the closing quotes or ">"

Comment: If you want to do it properly, then you should not handle this on a text basis, but parse it into a DOM structure, and then remove elements and shorten text nodes …

Comment: Thanks 04FS, could you give an example please. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: That would be a way more complex process than what you are doing now (just “cutting off” somewhere), and nothing that one could give a “quick example” for. If you want to go this way, then you need to acquire some base knowledge on how to work with and traverse a DOM tree first of all.